# How to chnage properties file and dependancy dynamically in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml

i want to create an functionality in which i have to change the dependancy in POM file and properties file dynamically.

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you mean. Can you please explain it in more detail? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate more on the requirements and put more info on what you're trying to achieve.

1. You can use Maven profiles to change dependencies dynamically. [Reference Link](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-profiles) also [Similar Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553458/change-maven-dependencys-version-by-using-different-maven-profiles)
2. For properties file, follow these [Reference Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) also [Similar Solution](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profiles-example/)